# I have a function or query to execute. The query is in form of a string(within single quotes).Now, how to unmask the query from string form & execute

Tags: python, string, function, substring, python-3.8

```
s='Search(using=client, index="5").query("match",Job_Title=Sales Executive).query("match",Job_Group=Sales).query("match",Job_State=Karnataka).query("match",Skills_Required=marketing)'
```

I want to run `response = s.execute()`

s is the Elastic search query within a single quote in form of a single string. I want to execute it, But it will get executed only i can unmask it from the string form to function form.How do i do it.

Answer (score 0):

What you're probably looking for is pythons built-in [`eval()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#eval) method. It evaluates a string expression and returns to you the result. Usage:

```
response = eval(s)
```

Before you decide to use `eval` however, first see [why using eval might be dangerous](https://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201206/eval_really_is_dangerous.html) and why [`ast.literal_eval()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) should be preferred.